# Detect specific content in strings included numbers and varying spaces in Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to search a string by using regex in NotePad++.
The sample string as

```
1.)  Abc
2.)   Cd
```

How I can detect the spaces after ')' (Assuming that the number of spaces is not static) and the first characters in each line.
Thank you!

Comment: You've not made it clear exactly what should (and should not) match, and not shown any efforts you've made to do this yourself. This isn't a regex or code writing service.

Comment: If you want to remove those spaces and/or find the characters from the beginning of the line to that `)`, it's something like `(?m)^([^)]*)\)([^\S\r\n]+)`

Comment: Dear sln, your comment is solved my problem, but I could not mark as an answer, can you repost as an answer, and explain all syntax in the command.
Thank you!

Comment: @greenworld: All you need is `^[^)]*\)\h+` then. However, to stay on the same line, the `^[^)\n\r]*\)\h+` will be better. And if there are just digit(s) with `.`, then `^\d+\.\)\h+` will be even more precise.

Comment: Sure I'll explain in a post.

Comment: Dear Mr. Wiktor Stribiżew, sln, do you know how to match the string from the beginning until first uppercase character, in this case, it will match from the beginning until "A" or "C" character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work `(?m)^([^)]*)\)([^\S\r\n]+)`
Capture groups are included if you want to rearrange or anything else.

Explained

```
 (?m)                          # Inline modifier, MULTI-Line mode
 ^                             # Beginning of line
 ( [^)]* )                     # (1), Negative optional class, 0 to many non paren ')'
 \)                            # The paren ')'
 ( [^\S\r\n]+ )                # (2), Required horizontal (non-crlf) whitespace
                               # Could use '\h+' here but it resolves to what's above
```

Comment: Can you suggest me the document which easy to learn regex command, actually I do not understand what is a "Negative optional class" ...

Comment: @greenworld - I think notepad uses the boost regex engine. You can start with this page http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html. Further down there is Perl syntax you can check for constructs. The `[^)]` is a character class negated by the `^`. Means _anything not a `)` literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spaces in regex using `\s`. Since you don't know how many you can indicate a quantifier `*`, which will match any number of the previous character/group (including 0 times!):

```
\s*
```

Or if you know there will be at least 1 space, you can use `+` which matches one or more:

```
\s+
```

Comment: If I know at least two spaces, how I can adjust the command? thank you.

Comment: You can use a bracket quantifier: {}. I would recommend looking for a guide. I just did a quick google search and found [this guide](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) as a sort of cheat sheet.